# Display progress in long running filter predicates

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a long predicate filtering in my app.
I need to show exact progress in percent, but I have access to no sort of progress within **Filter**.

```
public ICollectionView viewSource { get; set; }

viewSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Photos);
// this line takes 30 seconds
viewSource.Filter = i => (... & ... & .... long list of conditions)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap your `viewSource.Filter` filtering functionality in a method which is processed on a `BackgroundWorker` thread.  If you are able to determine the number of `objects` to filter, you can increment a `counter` which in conjunction with the starting count can be used to provide progress.

**EDIT:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Threading;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly Random random = new Random();
    private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;
    private ObservableCollection<int> CollectionOfInts { get; set; }
    private ICollectionView ViewSource { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CollectionOfInts = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        var nextRandom = this.random.Next(1, 200);
        for (var i = 0; i <= nextRandom + 2; i++)
        {
            this.CollectionOfInts.Add(this.random.Next(0, 2000));
        }

        this.ViewSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.CollectionOfInts);
        this.ProgressBar.Maximum = this.CollectionOfInts.Count;
    }

    private void RunFilter()
    {
        this.ViewSource.Filter = LongRunningFilter;
    }

    private bool LongRunningFilter(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                new Action(() => this.ProgressBar.Value++)
                );
            var value = (int) obj;
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            return (value > 5 && value < 499);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.ProgressBar.Value = 0;
            this.backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            this.backgroundWorker.DoWork += delegate { RunFilter(); };
            this.backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The basic principle here is that I know how many `objects` I have to filter (`this.CollectionOfInts.Count`), so this is my `Maximum` value (100%).  I start the filtering on a `BackgroundWorker` thread.  Starting the `BackgroundWorker` with `RunWorkerAsync` calls the `RunFilter` method which in turn calls `LongRunningFilter` which actually performs the filtering (I placed a `Thread.Sleep` in there to simulate a time consuming filter).  `LongRunningFilter` is called once for each object in the `ViewSource` and so can be used to `increment` a `counter` to inform us which iteration it is currently on.  Use this in conjunction with your known `Maximum` and you have a form of progress.

I realise this is not exactly how your actual problem works, however, it shows the concept.

Comment: And how to ( or where to) increment the "counter"? @Veleous

Comment: @AVEbrahimi I have added an example for your review.